# What is the most modern calculus book in Latin?

Tags: mathematics

I wonder if there is any modern math books especially calculus that is written in Latin like multivariable calculus, vector calculus etc.
Not knowing how modern the get, I'd like to know:
What is the most modern (by publication year or style) calculus book written in Latin?

Comment: Good question! Would it make sense to reword the question to "what is the most modern calculus book in Latin?"? That would be easy to answer with examples and would answer your original question.

Comment: Yes it definitely it would make sense!

Answer (score 7):

This might be way older that you would like, but at least it is a concrete example.
Euler's [*Introductio in analysin infinitorum* from 1748](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introductio_in_analysin_infinitorum) is a relatively modern calculus book.
Euler came up with much of modern calculus notation, so the books before him are probably nowhere near as readable for the modern reader.

The book is available free online at the Euler Archive in volumes [one](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/101/) and [two](https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-works/102/).

Comment: *Elementorum physicae mathematicae* from 1840 by Andreas Caraffa is a bit more modern, but it is more than just Calculus.   https://books.google.com/books?id=UhHvnAEACAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false